# Php script for array exercises

Tags: php, scripting

I'm trying to resolve [This exercise][1]...
I'm writing the follow code:

```
$steps=8;
$path=['U','D','D','D','U','D','U','U'];

function countingValleys($steps, $path) {
    // Write your code here
    $sea=0;
    $valley=0;
    $key=0;
    function check($steps, $path,$valley,$key,$sea){
       ($path[$key]=='D')?$sea--:$sea++;
       if($sea<0) $valley++;
       while($sea<0){
           $key++;
           if($key==$steps) return $valley; else ($path[$key]=='D')?$sea--:$sea++;
      }
       $key++;
       if($key==$steps) return $valley; else check($steps, $path,$valley,$key,$sea);
     }
     $Return=check($steps, $path,$valley,$key,$sea);
     return $Return;
}
$Return=countingValleys($steps, $path);
echo $Return;
```

suddenly it returns an empty string instead the result it should... Can you help me?
Thanks
[1]: https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/counting-valleys/problem?h_l=interview&playlist_slugs%5B%5D=interview-preparation-kit&playlist_slugs%5B%5D=warmup

Comment: Why do you have a function inside a function? You really should spend some time formatting this code. It will be much more easier to evaluate.

Answer (score 0):

It's empty string because `$Return=countingValleys($steps, $path);` takes null value.
The reason is that in `check()` method you return `$valley` or you call recursively `check()` but you also have to return it otherwise the method act like it's `void` method.

```
<?php

$steps = 8;
$path = ['U', 'D', 'D', 'D', 'U', 'D', 'U', 'U'];

function countingValleys($steps, $path)
{
    // Write your code here
    $sea = 0;
    $valley = 0;
    $key = 0;
    function check($steps, $path, $valley, $key, $sea)
    {
        ($path[$key] == 'D') ? $sea-- : $sea++;
        if ($sea < 0) $valley++;
        while ($sea < 0) {
            $key++;
            if ($key == $steps) return $valley; else ($path[$key] == 'D') ? $sea-- : $sea++;
        }
        $key++;
        if ($key == $steps) return $valley; else return check($steps, $path, $valley, $key, $sea);
    }

    $Return = check($steps, $path, $valley, $key, $sea);
    return $Return;
}

$Return = countingValleys($steps, $path);
echo $Return;
// output 1
```